# extracting youtube-dl command output to variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, youtube-dl

so for the last couple days I've been trying to extract the value of a youtube dl command unfortunately with no success, I might be doing something wrong here's my code:

```
youtube-dl --get-filename -o "Download/%%(title)s.mp3" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
```

this code returns `Download\Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video).mp3` I need to get this output into a variable, I have already tried with `for /f` with no success, it gives this error:

```
WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor. ERROR: Unsupported URL: https://www.youtube.com/
```

Edit: here's what I tried

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('youtube-dl --get-filename -o "Download/%%(title)s.mp3" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ') do set "myvar=%%a" 
echo %myvar%
```

Comment: There are literally thousands of examples of this task on this site. You shouldn't be looking specifically for answers which use `youtube-dl` it is irrelevant to the issue. What you need is how to capture the result of a command as a variable. If you search for that, using the search facility at the top of the page, you'll notice that the majority of solutions use a [tag:for-loop] i.e. `For /F`, and as a result, you should be able to do the same yourself. To find out how to use a for loop, open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the presented information.

Comment: If you specifically wanted help with the `For /F` command you used, and which produced the `WARNING` output, then please post exactly the content of that command, i.e. the FOR, the IN, and the DO portions. We cannot guess what you've used!

Comment: As you've not placed your URL inside doublequotes, the cmd.exe instance which parses the parenthesized command is probably omitting the `=` delimiter. Please try either doublequoting your URL, or escaping the `=` character with a caret, `^`.

Comment: @Compo Same error with a caret and double quoting produces no output

Comment: @Xetap `this code returns ...` It returns `Download\%(title)s.mp3` here.

Comment: @dvix it returns that value when on its own without the for /f brackets, until now no idea if something is wrong with my for /f code or with youtube-dl itself

Comment: @Xetap If it doesn't work on its own, it will certainly not work any better in a `for /f` loop. So first thing is make up your mind on what command you mean to actually run.

Comment: I have provided proof that my previous comment was correct @Xetap, by adding it as an answer. So, if you're still having issues, it must be because you've not shown us what you're really doing. Therefore, with my special mind reading hat on, your URL, isn't really like that, it is a variable which you've previously defined, so when it's expanded it is no longer the same,_(as it was parsed/modified at definition time)_, and/or you're running that loop inside a parenthesized block, and not utilising delayed expansion.

Comment: @ Compo nah man it's all working now thanks to you I really appreciate it, I guess I need to learn more. thanks again

Comment: I assume, because I told you what do do, and proved it to be correct, your problem @Xetap, wasn't with learning capacity. You stated, "Same error with a caret and double quoting produces no output", in response to my very simple and basic instructions, so your issue is in following simple and basic instructions, or being untruthful that you had done so!

Comment: @Compo untruthful ? really? why would I be untruthful? you somehow seem to be taking personal or I don't know, I messed up with the caret thing and added it after the equal sign that returned the same error as before and that's on me and as for adding double quotes I added it to my code as I asked, here have a look and try it if you want :
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('youtube-dl --get-filename -o "Download/%%(title)s.mp3" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"') do set "myvar=%%a"

Comment: Even using the modified example in your comment above, _(with `https://www.` removed by the site software)_, the example you've provided above sets the variable as intended. However you'll also get a message `WARNING: The URL doesn't specify the protocol, trying with http`, but this doesn't affect the result, _and can be removed by redirection, `… "youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" 2^>NUL')`_. You are therefore still doing something wrong, because the doublequoted method is the proper syntax, _(not the escape method)_, and works in my comment, answer, and using your provided code above!

Comment: @ Compo sorry to bother you again, according to ss64.com "Unicode format cannot be read by the FOR command which expects ASCII", here for example:
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('youtube-dl --get-filename -o "%%(title)s.mp3" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIWet8EJJtg"') Do @echo "%%~G"
the title of the video is ♫【Nightcore】- Heart Attack but the Unicode characters are omitted in the for /f output resulting in "Nightcore- Heart Attack.mp3", is there anyway around it to get the Unicode characters to display properly?

Comment: I see what you did here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're fortunate, that the PC, I'm currently repairing has a copy of the youtube executable on it!

I therefore tested what I put in the comments, here's the results!

Your example, with an unquoted URL and no escape characters:

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('youtube-dl --get-filename -o "Download/%%(title)s.mp3" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ') Do @Echo "%%~G"
```

Returns:

> ```batch-file
> WARNING: Falling back on generic information extractor.
> ERROR: Unsupported URL: https://www.youtube.com/
> ```

I said, "Please try either doublequoting your URL":

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('youtube-dl --get-filename -o "Download/%%(title)s.mp3" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"') Do @Echo "%%~G"
```

This returns:

> ```batch-file
> "Download\Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video).mp3"
> ```

and, "or escaping the `=` character with a caret, `^`"

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('youtube-dl --get-filename -o "Download\%%(title)s.mp3" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v^=dQw4w9WgXcQ') Do @Echo "%%~G"
```

Returns:

> ```batch-file
> "Download\Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video).mp3"
> ```

It seems that my advice was absolutely correct for the issue you raised.

BTW, on the last example, because the path separator on Windows is <kbd>\</kbd> not <kbd>/</kbd>, I changed `Download/` to `Download\`